# Better way of assigning the variable during LINQ Query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have this piece of code:

```
//This is coming from an Excell sheet
var ListOfPropertyElements = dataInternal
           .Select(element => new
           {
               PersonName = DC.EncryptToString((string)element.PersonName),
               KeyDate = (DateTime)element.KeyDate
           })
           .Distinct().ToList();


 List<int> idList = new List<int>();//This is used to delete records

 //trying to check do I have records in SQL with the ListOfPropertyElements     
 foreach (var listitems in ListOfPropertyElements)
 {
     var temp = dbContext.tbl_person
       .Where(item => item.ItemName == listitems.personName &&                  
                      item.KeyDate == listitems.KeyDate)
       .Select(item => item.personID)
       .ToArray();

       if (temp.Length > 0)
       {
           idList.Add(temp[0]);
       }
 }
```

As an end result I am getting a list of integers. What bothers me the way how I fill that idList variable. During LINQ execution, I convert the result to Array, then bounce it back to list, along with if defense.

Is there a more elegant way to do this? I dont like my Rambo style at all :(

Comment: Just remove `ToArray()`, add `Take(1)` and call `idList.AddRange(temp)`. I'm sure you can simplify the `foeach()` away as well. What have you tried?

Comment: I just updated my question

Comment: Instead of `ToArray()` don't you just want `FirstOrDefault()` since you're only adding a single item to `idList`?

Comment: You generating N queries to the data source. If your `ListOfPropertyElements` not too big, you can try to generate more optimal query.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev anonymous classes override `Equals` such that they are equal if all properties are equal.  So the Distinct could be removing items.

Comment: You want find person's ID from database(`dbContext.tbl_person`) which names are in the list `ListOfPropertyElements`?

Comment: @juharr Oh, thanks, I didn't know this. That's really interesting. Removed my comment in order to not confuse anybody else.

Comment: Just updated the quesiton with more comments

Comment: What is `DC.EncryptToString`? What is `dataInternal`? Is those from external source?

Comment: DC is just external class that does AES Encryption on the string. Not related . Data internal is an instance of Person class, with the properties such as Name, Lastname etc... nothing more.

Comment: Can I assume that the `ListOfPropertyElements` is in-memory data (no need materialization)?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly populate `idList`:-

```
List<int> idList =  dbContext.tbl_person
                    .Where(item => ListOfPropertyElements.Select(x => x.PersonName)
                                                         .Contains(item.PersonName) 
                                && ListOfPropertyElements.Select(x => x.KeyDate)
                                                         .Contains(item.KeyDate)))
                    .Select(item => item.personID).ToList();
```

Comment: listitem is a member of ListOfPropertyElements in a foreach loop. How can this work?

Comment: Give me back this error: 
Local sequences can not be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators . Exception: the Contains operator .

Comment: If I use contains, then it error complaining it can not convert lambda expression type to type "Anonymous type"

Comment: (parameter) ? x

ERROR: Cannot convert Lambda expression to type 'Anonymous Type#1' becouse it is not a delegate type.

Comment: @Rahin Singh. Thank you so much for spending your time on the chat while resolving this problem!!!.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I haven't compiled it. And I assume you aren't overly concerned with optimizing the number of iterations.

```
//Excel sheet data
var ListOfPropertyElements = dataInternal.Select(element => new { PersonName = DC.EncryptToString((string)element.PersonName),
                                                                  KeyDate = (DateTime)element.KeyDate }).Distinct();

//Filtered Id's
var idList = dbContext.tbl_person.Where(item => ListOfPropertyElements.Any(pElement => item.ItemName == pElement.PersonName && item.KeyDate == pElement.KeyDate))
                                 .Select(fItem => fItem.personID).ToList();
```